# Why does trait implementation only conflict within same crate?

Tags: rust

and furthermore, it depends on the details of the trait.

I have two minimal crates. The first is a library crate `foo`, containing

```
#![allow(incomplete_features)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

pub trait KnownSize: Sized {
    const N: usize = core::mem::size_of::<Self>();
}
impl<T: Sized> KnownSize for T {}

pub trait SizeIs<const N: usize> {}
impl<T: KnownSize> SizeIs<{ T::N }> for T {}

struct X(u32);

// Uncommenting either of these lines breaks due to conflict with blanket impls above
// impl KnownSize for X {}
// impl SizeIs<4> for X {}
```

In crate `bar`, I have

```
use foo::*;

struct X(u32);

// Uncommenting this line breaks due to conflict with blanket impl in `foo`
// impl KnownSize for X {}

// However this line works! (and is required if I want to use the `X: SizeIs<4>` impl)
impl SizeIs<4> for X {}
```

```
> rustc --version
rustc 1.76.0-nightly (6b771f6b5 2023-11-15)
```

Comment: My guess is that they should conflict, but don't currently because `generic_const_exprs` isn't fully implemented yet.

Comment: Report an issue. This is likely unsound.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/118343